# button click => add new tab in xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I was wondering if you can help me something about the programming language C # in Xamarin tutorial
(button add dynamique tab), Can I add a button that add tabs like tabs in firefox

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add tabs dynamically but have no idea what you mean like in firefox. To add tabs dynamically you can do something like this:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    private int _count; 

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        var button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

        ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;

        button.Click += AddTab;
    }

    private void AddTab(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _count += 1;
        var tab = ActionBar.NewTab();
        tab.SetTag("Tab" + _count);
        tab.SetText("tab - " + _count);
        var temp = _count;
        tab.TabSelected +=
            (o, args) => { Toast.MakeText(this, "Tab " + temp + " selected!", ToastLength.Long).Show(); };
        ActionBar.AddTab(tab);
    }
}
```